# windows batch file to submit a doc file for printing on the default printer

Tags: microsoft-word, batch, printing

I have a list of word docs coming into a particular folder in my server. I need to submit them to the printer . I cannot maunually keep on printing as this is going to get tedious. I need a windows batch file to submit this for printing into the printer and I am going to schedule it from a task scheduler to execute this every 5 mins . Can anybody help me with the batch file.?

Thank You...

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to attempt it yourself and ask any questions when you get stuck. We aren't fans of doing everything for you. Have to show some effort. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works with me on Win 7 Enterprise with Word2010

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Winword.exe" /mFilePrintDefault YourFile.doc
```

Of course you need to check the path of Word and your file

See also [MS Word Print from CMD Line](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Microsoft-Word-1058/Printing-command-line-1.htm)